# Array initialization when using new

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, initialization

In C#  I could do this:

```
char[] a = new char[] {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

But can I do something like that in C++? I tried:

```
char *a = new char [] {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

But it doesn't compile.

Comment: Try `char a[] = {'a', 'a', 'a'};`. Much easier!

Comment: Specify the size: `char *a = new char [3] {'a', 'a', 'a'};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the C++ spec (which doesn't let this simple construct to compile). You need to supply the size

```
char *a = new char [3] {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1469 . Note that if you parenthesize the type name it is a *type-id* and not a *new-type-id* and hence syntactically allows you to omit the size expression. So you may be able to find an implementation that allows you to say

```
char *a = new (char[]){'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

Althought it is clear that it wasn't the explicit intent that this is possible (and some rules in the `new` paragraphs can be interpreted to forbid it).

Comment: I don't think `new` should be used here at all. Use the stack or a container.

Comment: @inverse you should add that to the question as a comment. i do not recommend anything in my answer. i just fixed his syntax.

Comment: all the replies that talk about stack arrays or vectors do not really answer his question about the syntax of new.

Answer (score 6):

why not just do this? :

```
char a[] = {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

Also avoid using arrays completely. Use `std::vector`

Comment: It would be great to add something on initializers for `std::vector`, like "if you're lucky enough to have a compiler supporting c++11, then you can so and so."

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I am not current on C++11, my focus has shifted to C#. But I would not mind if you want to add something to the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to use an array in C++. Use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

You can even initialise it to 3 'a's.

```
std::vector<char> vectorOfChars(3, 'a');
```

If your compiler supports C++11, you can even use an initialiser list.

```
std::vector<char> vectorOfChars{'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this:

```
   const char a[] = {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like;

```
char a[] = {'a', 'a', 'a'};
```

Check out [`Arrays (C++)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkxxx2e.aspx) from *MSDN*.

Answer (score 0):

string a = "aaa";
a[0] , a[1] ..etc
This will be much easier if you wanna make 2-D arrays of string..etc